# What's the use of "that" in this case?

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, optional-that, content-clauses

What's the difference between the two?

> You know that it is true.
>   You know it is true.

Are those the same perfectly in conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are basically the same, stating that the listener has knowledge about something.  The nuance is

> You know **that** it is true.

Places explicit emphasis on what is known.